# Can I tie the lugs together in a load center to provide 120 VAC only?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am installing an off-grid solar + battery + inverter power system in my garage. I am in the US. I want to use a single phase 120 VAC inverter to supply power for lighting and a garage door opener. I do NOT want to purchase a split phase 120/240 inverter because they are generally higher powered than I need and more expensive than lower powered 120-only inverters. The inverter will be the only power source for the garage. There will be no grid connection.

Can I jumper the L1 and L2 lugs together inside a standard 120/240 load center so I can use all the breaker slots?

Obviously I will not be able to supply power to any 240 VAC loads, but that is OK with me. I am doing the whole garage and I will just not have any 240 VAC loads or outlets anywhere.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed due tot he shopping/product recommendation aspect that's currently there. Will you consider re-writing it so that your question focuses mainly on the possibility of using a standard split-phase load center for 120v only? I think that would make it on topic.

Comment: A frame challenge: Use 12V DC garage door opener and lighting, and skip the inverter. Such garage door openers exist per a quick Google. Then you won't have to buy an expensive inverter to handle the startup current of the opener motor.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippNagel. I edited it. Hope it is OK now.

Comment: Given that you have a limited power source and have described a need for exactly two circuits, I find it hard to envision what you need every space with a breaker for...? If that's a concern, follow the advice always given here, and spend the price of a latte on a panel with more spaces once, at the beginning...

Comment: @Ecnerwal I will get a reasonable load center in case I expand. Thanks. But I will go ahead and put my first two breakers next to each other. It was bugging me that I would have to leave every other slot blank. It was not so much that I was concerned about running out of slots.

Comment: @Triplefault There is already a 120 VAC garage door opener in the garage. When I googled 12 V garage door openers, I did not readily find a large number of options. Personally, for this reason and other reasons, I do not subscribe to the idea that running everything on 12 VDC is better. But I appreciate you raising the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can jumper the two hots together. The only catch is that you can't normally put two wires under one lug (i.e., hot in to L1, jumper from L1 to L2) so you have to use some other method to connect the one incoming hot to both lugs.

Comment: Noted. I will investigate my options.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from manassehkatz's warning (something which is present on my cottage, or was; I assume they fixed it)...

By the way, one trick you can do is to back-feed with a breaker.  The breaker has to be tied down if you do (so it can't come off in your hand).  So for instance you can jumper the panel's 2 main lugs *to each other* and then back-feed into 1 pole of a 2-pole breaker (it'll need to be 2-pole because they don't make tie-down kits for 1-pole breakers, but, you can use the other pole for an ordinary load).

Further, with this method, it's not hard to install a second back-feed breaker and interlock them with e.g. a Siemens ECSBPK01 "generator" interlock kit.  You would do that if you had 15-20A of utility power coming into the garage and wanted the opportunity to use that from time to time.   In that case the second poles would be wasted.  The ECSBPK01 takes care of breaker hold-down, but it only works in 12-space or larger Siemens panels.